# Download Updates with crontab

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, updates, cron

I'm trying to set up crontab so it downloads all available package updates without installing them. Unfortunately it seems like it doesn't run.

my crontab command in `sudo crontab -e`:

```
1 */1 * * * sudo apt-get -d upgrade
```

this should go out on every first minute of every hour and download all available packages to /var/cache/apt/archives/.

When I run the command manually from the command line it works like intended.

Maybe I'm getting things wrong with sudo and the crontab as root idk. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should look into `unattended-upgrades`.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` in command run from root crontab. also try specify full path and temporally add log file to see whats going on. so the command `1 */1 * * * /usr/bin/apt-get -d upgrade &>/tmp/cronapt.log`

Comment: Jos thanks for the comment I'm aware of that package but I'd rather do it without it.

@LeonidMew Thanks for the comment I applied the changes (changed the time so it ran within the next 5 minutes)  - no files were downloaded and the logfile is completely empty.

Comment: I make error in redirection of output, this code should work: `1 */1 * * * /usr/bin/apt-get -d upgrade >/tmp/cronapt.log 2>&1`  At least it will make log file with error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First way, run `sudo crontab -e` and add/change following line:

```
1 * * * * /usr/bin/apt-get -d upgrade >/tmp/cronapt.log 2>&1
```

Then check `/tmp/cronapt.log` for errors.

Second way is to put the following shell script in the `/etc/cron.hourly` folder, make it executable and owned by `root:root`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/apt-get -d upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks the first solution is exactly what I want.
For it to work you'll also want to put a "-yy" flag in there.
30 * * * * /usr/bin/apt-get -d -yy upgrade

Answer (score 3):

**Apt already has a feature to do this.**

Edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`

Locate the entry:

```
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
```

This entry tells apt whether or not to download new packages using apt's `--download-only` option. "0" means the option is disabled, so apt will install the packages it downloads.

Change the "0" to a different number to enable `--download-only`. The number represents the frequency of download in days: "1" for daily, "2" for every second day, "7" for weekly, etc. The documentation for these options is in the file `/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily`

If you want to pull ALL available packages (instead of only security updates), then you must also make a small edit to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. Uncomment the sources you want to include. This is not recommended for PPAs and other non-Ubuntu software, but easily possible if you want to take the risk.

Comment: the file you mentioned "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic" does not exist on my system. 
There is "01autoremove-kernels" and after that "20dbus" but no "10periodic"

Comment: Ah, so either you are on a server or you are on a very stripped-down desktop. There is no magic incantation; it's just an apt setting in a text file. You can, if you wish, create the file and put the line in it.

Comment: It's a month old install of Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon so nothing fancy :D

Comment: We can help a lot with Ubuntu, but we don't keep track of the myriad changes that unofficial derivatives make. Your best option is to ask Mint support.